# Not constant ping to cisco switch

Tags: switch

I have LAN made up from CISCO 2960 switches. 
Topology is Star. One core switch and others are on floors. 
Sometimes ping is lost to one of the switches which is in server room. 
There is no loop, we have checked. 
Each time we have to reload switch and for some time it is ok. 
But time after, it repeats again - pings are not continous. 
Servers are connected to that switch, 1 hub and 1 switch also is connected. 
What may be the problem?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. A network diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Also, whether or not the switch management answer a ping is really no indication of whether or not the switch is actually switching correctly.

Comment: Please provide the information @RonMaupin has posted above if you need help figuring out the problem.